# How to open Nautilus at current command line directory?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, filesystem

I was wondering if anybody knew a command that would allow me to open a Nautilus (if that's the right name for the Ubuntu graphic/window explorer) window from the command line at the current directory that the user is at.

So, if I open a command line, and type:

```
cd /home/myUser/some/long/path/to/a/directory
```

Then, I'd like to be able to issue some command:

```
nautilus open-sesame
```

And have a graphic window opened to `/home/myUser/some/long/path/to/a/directory`. Is this even possible?

Comment: `nautilus .` where the full stop (or period as the Americans might say) is the current directory, or current working directory.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can type in the terminal:

```
cd /home/myUser/some/long/path/to/a/directory
```

and then:

```
nautilus .
```

The above command will open nautilus in the folder `/home/myUser/some/long/path/to/a/directory` (the period is the current directory)

Or in the Terminal just type:

```
nautilus /home/myUser/some/long/path/to/a/directory
```

Comment: won't work in `ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya It does work on my `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` with a fresh install and nothing special installed.

Comment: `alias open="nautilus"`, and you can using `$ open <PATH_HERE>` like the MacOS.

Answer (score 17):

In order to avoid nasty warnings in my terminal I use `nohup`. To have it detached from my terminal I'm adding `&` at the end of my command. I also use the `-w` flag to open in a new window.

```
nohup nautilus -w . &
```

Note that, `nohup` will create a file with warnings.

You can send that to `/dev/null` like this:

```
nohup nautilus -w . > /dev/null &
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to type all of this all everytime you want to open nautilus, you can make a function and place it in your .bashrc or into a file that is sourced when you open your console.

```
open() {
    nohup nautilus -w $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}
```

You could then use :

```
$ open path/to/open/
```

I would prefer that over an alias as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1104175/393936) since it allows you to specify the path to open in nautilus.

Comment: Smooth command! I was just trying to open Nautilus from terminal and detach it from the parent process (i.e., the terminal), but I was unsuccessful (I tried `nohup` and `&`) your combination `nohup nautilus -w . &` works perfect.

Answer (score 16):

You can also do `gnome-open .`. `gnome-open` is similar to `open` on Mac which tries to open the file using the best matching application. By default, `gnome-open .` on Ubuntu will open the current directory in Nautilus.

There is an `open` command in Ubuntu as well but it does not work in this case.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 it isn't installed by default: "The program 'gnome-open' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
`sudo apt install libgnome2-bin`"

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: calling `gnome-open` directly is deprecated (it already was in 2014). Use the generic `xdg-open` instead.

Answer (score 13):

You should use `xdg-open .` (or `xdg-open <path>`) which is way more generic.

Answer (score 2):

To open nautilus from terminal.

`nautilus .`

To open nautilus in the background and still use the terminal.

`nohup nautilus . > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

You can also make that an alias.

`alias open='nohup nautilus . > /dev/null 2>&1 &'`

You can also add that alias to .bash_aliases, to have it persistent.

`echo "alias open='nohup nautilus . > /dev/null 2>&1 &'" >> .bash_aliases`

So now, after restarting the terminal, you can just type `open`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and I also experienced problems with some of the popular solutions above. What is currently working for me is:

```
nautilus -w $(pwd)
```

This method does not require additional installs, creating files, error handling, etc, and so *appears* to be the simplest.

I hope it helps!