# How can I open the present working directory (pwd) in Nautilus from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, gnome-terminal

How can I open a directory which I am currently working on from terminal in nautilus file manager?

Comment: Don't. Your question contains the term `present` working directory. The other does not contain that terminology (if uses `current`). If we keep the question, people searching on `pwd` will be redirected via this question to the other question.

Comment: As @Private says, we generally keep duplicates. We handle them by closing them. When a question is closed as a duplicate of another question, it is made to point clearly to that other question. For more details, you may want to see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type

```
nautilus .
```

There is no need to add more than the `.`

You could make this an alias: `alias n="nautilus ."` and then you can just type `n` in the commandline to open the cwd in nautilus.

This is a duplicate. Please see [How to open Nautilus at current command line directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226755/how-to-open-nautilus-at-current-command-line-directory).

Answer (score 3):

nautilus works as

```
nautilus [options] URIs...
```

Now, to open pwd in nautilus, we can do

```
nautilus ./
```