# Nautilus gives a warning when opened in the current directory from the terminal

Tags: command-line, xorg, nautilus, 17.10, pygi

I have referred this link:
[How to open Nautilus at current command line directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226755/how-to-open-nautilus-at-current-command-line-directory)

but ever since I upgraded to 17.10, running `nautilus .`, when I am already in a particular directory using `cd` in the terminal, gives me the following message.

```
sys:1: PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
```

How do I fix this?

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 in Xorg mode

Comment: Read [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/226757/480481) carefully, you need to `nautilus .`, not just `nautilus`.

Comment: @pomsky doing that I get a  warning everytime, I have updated the queston.

Comment: @devius OP changed the question invalidating Duplicate Close Candidate . Ironically it was a little devious.

Comment: The particular error you edited into your poast appears to be generated by the [Package python-nautilus.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-nautilus) If everything works as advertised otherwise, it's safe to ignore. If not you should likely [register a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open Nautilus from the current directory use:

```
nautilus .
```

To open with a given file selected use:

```
nautilus . -s filename
```

If the file name has spaces enclose it in double quotes (`"` ).

---

## Warning messages will appear

Nautilus, gedit and other apps are all based on Gnome Took Kit (GTK) and it is infamous for giving warning messages. 99% of the time you can ignore them. Does `nautilus` open ok with the current directory displayed? That is the only question. For Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with `xorg` there are lots of warnings:

```
$ nautilus .

(nautilus:18233): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:18233): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:18233): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:18233): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:18233): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Once again Nautilus works fine and these annoying warning messages are simply part of the Gnome back bone history of Ubuntu and other Linux distributions.

Comment: Thank you, but on doing that I get a warning everytime, what does it mean and how can I solve it? I have updated the question.

Comment: Nautilus, gedit and other apps are all based on Gnome Took Kit (GTK) and it is infamous for giving warning messages. 99% of the time you can ignore them. Does `nautilus` open ok with the current directory displayed?

Comment: See this to get rid of warnings https://askubuntu.com/a/1102117/393936

Answer (score 2):

The command `nautilus` takes as parameter the path to open, so if you want to open the current directory, you have to type

```
nautilus .
```

The `.`standing for current directory